# Solving a written problem involving system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

It is about a loan of 25.000.000.
Some of it was borrowed with 8% interest.
Some was borrowed with 10% interest.
And the rest with 9% interest.
We know that the sum that got 10% interest is 2.000.000 plus half of the 8% sum.
We also know that the total interest paid for the first year was 2.220.000.

I need to calculate the amount for each borrowed part using a system of linear equations

This is the system i came up with:

```
x + y + z = 25000000  all 3 parts should equal 25000000
y - 0.04x = 2000000   the sum that got 10% interest is 2.000.000 plus half of the 8% sum
0.08x + 0.1y + 0.09z = 2220000 the total interest paid is 2.220.000
```

When i solve it i get these values:

```
x = 15625000/3
y = 6625000/3
z = 52750000/3
```

I am not asking for the answer to this problem. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong/point me in the right direction

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some of it was borrowed with 8% interest.

Call that $x$.

> Some was borrowed with 10% interest.

Call that $y$

> And the rest with 9% interest.

Call that $z$.

> It is about a loan of 25.000.000.
>
> "x + y + z = 25000000  all 3 parts should equal 25000000"

Correct.  $x + y + z = 25000000$.

> We know that the sum that got 10% interest is 2.000.000 plus half of the 8% sum.
>
> "y - 0.04x = 2000000   the sum that got 10% interest is 2.000.000 plus half of the 8% sum"

Wait, what?  The "8% sum" refer to $x$.  We don't take half of 8% *of* $x$.  The "8%" just refers to what was borrowed *at* 8%.

So $y = 2000000 + \frac 12 x$.  That's what you should have written.

> We also know that the total interest paid for the first year was 2.220.000.
>
> "0.08x + 0.1y + 0.09z = 2220000 the total interest paid is 2.220.000"

Correct. $0.08 x + 0.1y + 0.09z = 2220000$

SO you have the three equations:

1. $x + y + z = 25000000$
2. $y = 2000000 + \frac 12 x$
3. $0.08 x + 0.1y + 0.09z = 2220000$

Solve them.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I appreciate your help so much :)